# java multithreading using join and handling interrupted execptions correctly

Tags: java, multithreading, join, interrupt, runnable

I have implemented multithreading in my service layer and want to ensure I have dealt with all cases where the threads are properly handled. I don't want to end up with some kind of exception (such as RuntimeEx or InterruptedEx) which could leave my app in a bad state.

My code is below.  Let me know if you can see any errors.  Recommendations are most welcome.  I'm using java 6.

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private List<MyData> list;
    private Person p;

    public MyRunnable(List<MyData> list, Person p) {
        this.list = list;  // this list is passed in and cannot be null
        this.p = p;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // before calling any of the services that gets data from the
        // database, check if the thread has been interrupted
        if (Thread.interrupted()) return;

        List<TypeA> aList;
        try {
            aList = getTypeAFromDatabase1(p);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        if (Thread.interrupted()) return;

        List<TypeB> bList;
        try {
            bList = getTypeBFromDatabase2(p);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        if (Thread.interrupted()) return;

        List<TypeC> cList;
        try {
            cList = getTypeCFromSomeWebService(p);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        MyData d = new MyData();
        d.setPerson(p);
        d.setTypeA(aList);
        d.setTypeB(bList);
        d.setTypeC(cList);
        list.add(d);
    }
}
```

Service that uses Runnable:

```
@JsonOperation
public static List<MyData> getMyData(MyParams params) throws Exception {

    List<Person> persons = params.getPersonList();

    try {
        // use synchronized list since all threads will add to this list
        List<MyData> retList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<MyData>());

        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();

        // For each person, start a new thread. It there are any runtime
        // exceptions thrown by any one thread, it will be caught by the
        // bigger try catch block. In case of runtime exception, we will
        // return back to the client right away but the other threads
        // are still processing
        try {

            for (Person p : persons) {
                // create a thread per person and start it
                Runnable task = new MyRunnable(retList, p);
                Thread worker = new Thread(task);
                threads.add(worker);
                worker.start();

                // remember the thread for later use
                threads.add(worker);
            }

            for (Thread thread : threads) {
                // wait for all threads (by waiting on one thread at a time)
                thread.join(3000);  //3 seconds between checking on this thread
            }

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            log.error(e);
            for (Thread thread : threads) {
                // try and send an interrupt to all threads so that they
                // don't fetch any more data from the database
                thread.interrupt();
            }
            throw e;
        }

        return retList;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: just btw... InterruptedExceptions are usually the result of something you want to deal with like another thread deliberately interrupting you. For example, you interrupt some threads. If they are waiting, then they will throw an interruptedexception. The way to deal with them is to put `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` (usually after doing some finalization like closing streams and whatnot)

Comment: `thread.join(3000)` "waits at most 3000 milliseconds for the thread to die" (copied from [ApiDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28long%29)). I.e. you still don't know if any of the threads hanged and never finished.

Comment: I did not yet read this closely enough to answer, but the `throws Exception` and `catch Exception` parts look *highly* dubious. Can you be more specific with the *type* of the exceptions being thrown?

Comment: that makes sense about hung threads and never exiting properly. Thanks!                                                         Also, since this is a json web service, all I really want to do with exception, when there is one in any of the threads: stop all threads(this is not needed but nice to have to free up cpu), log the error and return an error to the client.  When an exception is thrown, my wrapper function will convert that into a proper JSON response error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most situations it is easier to use *tasks* instead of *threads*. You start with an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), which restricts the number of threads and is shared across all service operations:

```
// inject with IoC framework
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

You use the method *invokeAll* to execute a *task* for each person. If the *tasks* do not finish within the given period, then the remaining tasks will be automatically cancelled. In this case, an exception is thrown when invoking the *get* method of the corresponding *future*. That means there is no need for additional exception handling.

```
public List<MyData> getMyData(MyParams params) throws Exception {
    List<Callable<MyData>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Person p : persons) {
        tasks.add(new Callable<MyData>() { // use Lambda in Java 8
            public MyData call() {
                MyData d = new MyData();
                d.setPerson(p);
                d.setTypeA(getTypeAFromDatabase1(p));
                d.setTypeB(getTypeBFromDatabase2(p));
                d.setTypeC(getTypeCFromSomeWebService(p));
                return d;
            }
        });
    }
    List<MyData> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Future<MyData> future : executor.invokeAll(tasks, 3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
        result.add(future.get());
    }
    return result;
}
```

There is no need to check the *interrupted* state within the *callable*. If a *blocking* operation is called within one of the methods, the method will automatically abort execution with an *InterruptedException* or some other exception (if it is implemented correctly). It is also possible to set the *interrupted* state instead of throwing an exception. However, that makes less sense for methods with return values.

Comment: Thanks this has been very helpful! In my Callables, I'm fetching data from the database or web service, etc.  Something can go wrong while doing this & my Callable will throw an ex. I've put a try/catch around .invokeAll() with a finally that calls executor.shutdownNow(). I have also checks for Thread.interrupted() from my Callable. I have ran failure test cases where 1)given time period expired 2)ex was thrown from Callable. Both of these were handled in catch.  Others scenarios I should be concerned with? Could a callable be interrupted\killed without an ex being thrown & caught?

Comment: OK, so I wanted to test the Interrupted thread scenario.  To do this, I simply added in my Callable: Thread.currenThread.interrupt(). Unexpectedly, the execution in my Callable thread continued after the call to interrupt. So, to force my current thread to stop processing the request, I'm thinking of adding the following check back in my Callable: if (Thread.interrupted()) {throw new InterruptedException();}

Comment: @user3474265: First, the catch block should be around _future.get()_, not around _invokeAll_. Second, there is no need to check _interrupted_ within the callables, if the blocking methods are implemented correctly. Third, you should check the _interrupted_ scenario by using a short timeout for _invokeAll_. Fourth, invoking _Thread.currentThread().interrupt()_ will only have an effect if there is a blocking operation later.